# virtual destructor's practical necessity in a particular case

Tags: c++, virtual-destructor

***C++03 5.3.5.3***

> In the first alternative (delete
>   object), if the static type of the
>   operand is different from its dynamic
>   type, the static type shall be a base
>   class of the operand’s dynamic type
>   and the static type shall have a
>   virtual destructor or the behavior is
>   undefined.

This is the theory. The question, however, is a practical one. What if the derived class adds no data members?

```
struct Base{
   //some members
   //no virtual functions, no virtual destructor
};
struct Derived:Base{
   //no more data members
   //possibly some more nonvirtual member functions
};

int main(){
     Base* p = new Derived;
     delete p; //UB according to the quote above
}
```

The question: ***is there any existing implementation on which this would really be dangerous?***
If so, could you please describe how the internals are implemented in that implementation which makes this code crash/leak or whatever? I *beg* you to believe, I *swear* that I have no intentions to rely on this behavior :)

Comment: um , wait. Just add a destructor to `Derived` and see weird things happen. Is it only restricted to that case above? Multiple inheritance could introduce funny cases where things may break too.

Comment: @ Johannes Schaub - litb:  I believe the author is intelligent enough to realize this. IMHO his/her intent was exactly as described: the `Derived` doesn't have any its own destructor (neither explicit nor automatically-generated due to non-trivial members)

Comment: Your `Base` class is `vector`, isn't it? ;-)

Comment: @Steve: No, it is not ))) As a matter of fact, I have changed my mind on the vector thing

Comment: @valdo I don't realy on such suspicions. He has said nothing about non-virtual destructorsin the base, and nothing about other forms of inheritance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One example is if you provide a custom `operator new` in `struct Derived`. Obviously calling wrong `operator delete` will likely produce devastating results.

Comment: But virtual d'tor will not be helpful. Instead you'll have to proviate a virtual `Dispose`/`Release` method, which will do both things: call the d'tor and free the memory.

Comment: P.S. In other words your answer is not directly related to the question.

Comment: @valdo: Having a virtual destructor in base class will be enough - C++ will do all the necessary stuff.

Comment: @sharptooth: I don't know which world you're living in. Obviously this doesn't work. (I've even checked it to be 100% sure).

Comment: @sharptooth: Sorry for my harsh language. What I mean that this is exactly the difference between good knowledge of standard and understanding how things are actually implemented. I'm not a guru of C++ standard, but from the implementation point of view it's clear for me there's no chance this things will work

Comment: @valdo: I use VC++9. I declared `class CBase` with a virtual destructor. I declared `class CDerived` that inherits from `class CBase` and has overloaded `operator new` and `operator delete`. When I do `CBase* base = new CBase(); delete base;` I see overloaded `operator delete` being called. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @sharptooth: you'll see that during `new` the memory is allocated according to `CDerived`. But upon `delete` the memory is freed according to `CBase`. And all the d'tors will be called correctly.

Comment: @sharptooth: The point is that `new/delete` operators are not (and can't be) **virtual**.

Comment: @valdo: In my example `class CBase` has no overloaded operators, only `class CDerived` has them and memory is allocated/deallocated with the same set of operators once there's a virtual destructor in `class CBase`.

Comment: @sharptooth: Oops... I think you may be right here... (I've made a syntax mistake when I tested it). According to the compiler-generated code I can see that compiler actually generates 2 version of d'tors: one that just destroys the object, and the one that destroys it and also frees its memory (aka `scalar deleting destructor'). And when you `delete` such an object exactly this kind of virtual d'tor is called. I take my words back and vote +1 for you :)

Comment: @sharptooth: Didn't know this. Thanks. P.S. I still believe regarding the original question that there's no problem with not providing a destructor is `Derived`, unless you do some specific things (such as you described for instance).

Comment: @valdo: It doesn't matter if there's a user-defined destructor - C++ will have to deduce and call proper deallocation function (`operator delete`). If there's no virtual destructor in the base class such deduction might be impossible. And once wrong deallocation function is called all bets are off.

Comment: @sharptooth: I never said "user-defined" d'tor. This may also be implicit d'tor. The point it that if this d'tor doesn't have anything specific (compared to the base class) - then it's not practically needed.

Comment: @valdo: Yes, but the destructor in base class must be declared and it must  be declared as virtual - that's the key to magic.

Answer (score 1):

I know of no implementation on which the above would be dangerous, and I think it unlikely that there ever will be such an implementation.

Here's why:

"undefined behaviour" is a catch-all phrase meaning (as everyone knows), anything could happen. The code could eat your lunch, or do nothing at all.

However, compiler *writers* are sane people, and there's a difference between undefined behaviour at compile-time, and undefined behaviour at run-time. If I was writing a compiler for an implementation where the code snippet above was dangerous, **it would be easy to catch and prevent at compile time.** I can says it's a compilation error (or warning, maybe): `Error 666: Cannot derive from class with non-virtual destructor.`

I think I'm allowed to do that, because the compiler's behaviour in this case is *not* defined by the standard.

Comment: AFAIK you can't compliantly add errors for "compile-time detected undefined behaviour" unless you can prove that it will **always** happen - and maybe not even then. You can definitely issue warnings, though, and the user is free to treat warnings as errors.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer for specific compilers, you'd have to ask the compiler writers. Even if a compiler works now, it might not do so in the next version so I would not rely on it.

Do you need this behaviour?

Let me guess that

1. You want to be able to have a base class pointer without seeing the derived class and
2. Not have a v-table in Base and
3. Be able to clean up in the base class pointer.

If those are your requirements it is possible to do, with boost::shared_ptr or your own adaptation.

At the point you pass the pointer you pass in a boost::shared_ptr with an actual "Derived" underneath. When it is deleted it will use the destructor that was created when the pointer was created which uses the correct delete. You should probably give Base a protected destructor though to be safe.

Note that there still is a v-table but it is in the shared pointer deleter base not in the class itself.

To create your own adaptation, if you use boost::function and boost::bind you don't need a v-table at all. You just get your boost::bind to wrap the underlying Derived* and the function calls delete on it.

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case, where you do not have any data member declared in the derived class and if you do not have any custom new/delete operators (as mentioned by Sharptooth), you may not have any problems ,but do you guarantee that no user will ever derive your class? If you do not make your `Base's` destructor virtual, there is no way for any of the classes derived from `Derived` to call their destructors in case the objects of derived classes are used via a `Base` pointer.

Also, there is a general notion that if you have virtual functions in your base class, the destructor should be made virtual. So better not surprise anybody :)

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with 'Roddy'.

Unless you're writing the code for perverted compiler designed for a non-existing virtual machine just to prove that so-called *undefined behavior* can bite - there's no problem.

The point of 'sharptooth' about custom `new/delete` operators is inapplicable here. Because virtual d'tor and won't solve in any way the problem he/she describes.

However it's a good point though. It means that the model where you provide a virtual d'tor and by such enable the polymorphic object creating/deletion is defective by design.
A more correct design is to equip such objects with a virtual function that does two things at once: call its (correct) destructor, and also free its memory the way it should be freed. In simple words - destroy the object by the appropriate means, which are known for the object itself.

Comment: LOL. There's a "politically correct" way to refer to a person whose gender you don't know - you refer to such person as "they".